# Fast construction of unordered_map with nested vector with preallocation std::unordered_map<int, vector<Thing *>>?

Tags: c++

I want to create map of int to vector of Things*. I know that `Thing` will be 1-50 no more. How can I allocate 50 at start to speed up construction of map?

I tried three methods but still not sure if it enough fast. Can you suggest better optimization?
I was using c++ 10 years ago and I am not sure if I do it correctly. Can you help?
All optimization suggestions are welcome. Code is simplified from real problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

#include <time.h>

class Thing {
};

int main()
{
    clock_t start;
    start = clock();
    auto int_to_thing = std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<Thing *>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
            int_to_thing[i].push_back(new Thing());
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
            int_to_thing[i].push_back(new Thing());
        }
    }
    std::cout << (clock() - start) << std::endl;

    start = clock();
    int_to_thing = std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<Thing *>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        int_to_thing[i].reserve(50);
        for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
            int_to_thing[i].push_back(new Thing());
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
            int_to_thing[i].push_back(new Thing());
        }
    }
    std::cout << (clock() - start) << std::endl;

    start = clock();
    int_to_thing = std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<Thing *>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        auto it = int_to_thing.find(i);
        if (it != int_to_thing.end()) {
            auto v = std::vector<Thing *>(50);
            auto pair = std::pair<int, std::vector<Thing *>>(i, v);
            int_to_thing.insert(pair);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
            int_to_thing[i].push_back(new Thing());
        }
    }
    std::cout << (clock() - start) << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For your timing run, did you compile with optimizations turned on?

Comment: Also, unless `Thing` is a polymorphic type, you should use a `vector<Thing>` instead.  If it is polymorphic, consider using a `vector<unique_ptr<Thing>>` instead so it manage the memory cleanup for you.

Comment: Perhaps pre-[`reserve` space in your `unordered_map` itself](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/reserve) to minimize rehashing? Not likely to make a big difference, but it's something.

Comment: profiling code isnt that simple. Either you turn on compiler optimizations then the compiler will optimize away everything, because the only observable behavior of your code is the print out of the timings, or you don't turn on optimizations then the measured times are close to meaningless

Comment: if you know there will be no more than 50 and you are willing to allocate memory for all 50 upfront, you could use a `std::array` instead, then you need not worry about how to best preallocate

Comment: @NathanOliver optimization no matter first memory allocation need to be improved to make progress.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Good idea thank you I will try it too.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Optimization will speed up instructions but not solve problem of complexity of algorithm - only human can break time not compiler. Array/vector is pretty similar here but vector is need here.

Comment: @Chameleon thats not right. The compiler can and tries to apply any optimization that does not change the observable behavior of the resulting program

Comment: @idclev463035818 No matter. Compiler can do all possible changes but will not see data and can not predict data. It can do programmer.

Comment: there is no data unknown to the compiler in what you measure

Answer (score 1):

Are you concerned about the construction of the `map` (then see @ShadowRanger's comment) or the construction of the vectors?

I assume that there are 1..50 `Thing`'s in a vector, NOT 1..50 vectors in a map.

Your code:

```
int_to_thing = std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<Thing *>>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    int_to_thing[i].reserve(50);
```

is the best option. It constructs a map of vectors and, inside the loop, creates each vector and pre-allocates room for 50 elements.

Without that `reserve()` you would likely encounter a couple of reallocation while pushing 50 elements into those vectors.

Using:

```
auto v = std::vector<Thing *>(50);
```

actually *creates* 50 elements in your vector,and default-initializes them. This may or may not cost you extra. Specifically, it will be cheap with your current use of pointers, and expensive if you switch to storing the `Thing` objects themselves.

Comment: `auto v = std::vector<Thing *>(50);` is bad because I do not know if will be 50. I know that can be 50. I tried this and I create exception (because of iterating empty elements)>

Comment: That is good idea first one 'int_to_thing[i].reserve(50);` looks very light!

Comment: I tested it not works. Better is `insert()` than `int_to_thing[i].reserve(50);`. It looks my code is still faster :) https://onlinegdb.com/ByVPt5amD

Comment: Little fixed but still insert is fast https://onlinegdb.com/Sy4jt5T7w.

Comment: @Chameleon - your code with `insert` does something different; what is the deal with `pair`s? And it doesn't push 25 `Thing`s into the vector.

Comment: Indeed I found this bug but after fixing longer code is stronger than shorter (mean faster). I will show you next version in exchange of help :)

Comment: See next solution works faster and is little counter intuitive. https://onlinegdb.com/SJXnF26Qv Less find operations and more reuse of iterators. This also cuts time in real code. Normally I code in Python 3.8+ since I can code faster (much more complex algorithms) but C++ is faster and become more usable after last changes. will use C++ more I think. Very good is to code some prototypes in Python - you learn algorithm faster - than writ in C++. In old times people prototype in C++ and write to assembler using listings :)

Comment: @Chameleon - your last case is still missing 24 `push_back`s!

Comment: Indeed I found this next bug. Thank you. I found that vector[].pushback() is better that searching key with complex syntax - it was mistake. I optimize program to 3.1+s but still not 3s or less but target is reachable after some thinking and minor optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unsure that something is fast enough then you are not measuring performance and this is prima facie evidence that you don’t care one iota about it. If you don’t measure it then you cannot claim anything about it. Measure it first before you do anything else. Otherwise you’ll waste everyone’s time. You work on an assumption that such preallocations will help. I have an inkling that they won’t help at all since you make so few of them, and you’re just wasting your time. Again: if you are serious about performance, you stop now, get measurements in place, and come back with some numbers to talk over. And don’t measure debug builds - only release builds with full optimization turned on, including link time code generation (LTCG). If you don’t optimize, you don’t care about performance either. Period. Full stop. Those are the rules.

Yes, you have code that times stuff but that’s not what measurements are about. They need to happen in the context of your use of the data, so that you can see what relative overhead you have. If the task takes an hour and you spend a second doing this “unoptimally”, then there’s no point in optimizing that first - you got bigger fish to fry first. And besides, in most context the code is cache-driven ie data access patterns determine performance so I don’t believe you’re doing anything useful at all at the moment. Such micro optimizations are totally pointless. This code doesn’t exist in a vacuum.  If it did, you can just remove it and forget about it all, right?

Comment: You judge and teach people to fast. It is not helpful and wrong. You can not reach understand by these limitations. Code which is in this example is executed 1 000 000 time or more and it is very important to optimize it. No only because of waste of power but also because it must be very fast. Your advice for beginner can be very good but not here.